# proof that $\frac{x^p - 1}{x-1} = 1 + x + \dots + x^{p-1}$ is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, factoring, irreducible-polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

I am reading the group theory text of [Eugene Dickson](https://archive.org/stream/lineargroupswith00dickuoft#page/20/mode/2up).  [Theorem 33](https://books.google.com/books?id=ao2vUmfQ6aQC&pg=PA21) shows this polynomial is irreducible

$$ \frac{x^p - 1}{x-1} = 1 + x + \dots + x^{p-1} \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$$

He shows this polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$ whenever $p$ is a primitive root mod $q$.

By [Dirichlet's theorem](http://cms.math.ca/cjm/a144567) there are infinitely many primes $q = a + ke$, so this polynomial is "algebraiclly irreducible", I guess in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

---

Do you really need a strong result such as the infinitude of primes in arithmetic sequences in order to prove this result?  Alternative ways of demonstrating this is irreducible for $p$ prime?

**COMMENTS** Dirichlet's theorem comes straight out of Dickson's book.  I am trying to understand why he did it.  Perhaps he did not know Eisenstein's criterion.  It's always good to have a few proofs on hand.

Another thing is that Eisenstein's criterion is no free lunch since it relays on Gauss lemma and ultimately on extending unique factorization from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: You can use a simple change of variables to show it's irreducible over $\Bbb Q$ (via Eisenstein). I am not sure what you are using Dirichlet's theorem to conclude anyway - is irreducible mod infinitely many primes supposed to imply it's irreducible over $\Bbb Q$ or something?

Comment: Do you want to show it is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[x]$ or in $\mathbb F_q[x]$?  Because those are two different things.  Over $\mathbb Z[x]$ I believe there's a cute trick using Eisenstein's criteria.

Comment: Look at this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial 

Look at the section on cyclotomic polynomials.

Comment: Actually the exact proof is on this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion#Examples

Comment: Look at that last wiki page for the "cyclotomic polynomial" example

Comment: @GregoryGrant Eisenstein's criterion is not a total free lunch as you have to invoke [Gauss' Lemma](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/210APage/handouts/gausslemma.pdf) (also [here](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/210BPage/handouts/math210b-Gauss-Eisenstein.pdf)) or detour into notions of [total ramification](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/totram.pdf) of primes.

Comment: @johnmangual Sure but it's a whole lot easier than Dirichlet's theorem

Comment: If you just want a proof of Gauss' lemma, then go [to Theorem 17.14 in this online textbook](http://abstract.ups.edu/aata/section-irreducible-poly.html).

Comment: To me this proof is completely absurd. Dirichlet's theorem is a thousand times more complicated than Eisenstein criterion (which can be proved without too much trouble by a good first year undergrad with a few hints), and using it to prove such an easy thing makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: Related posts (for the case of $\mathbb Z[x]$ or $\mathbb Q[x]$): 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82876/given-a-prime-p-in-mathbbn-is-a-fracxp2-1xp-1-irreducible-i http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215042/irreducibility-of-xp-1-cdots-x1 http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/215042

Answer (score 1):

To clarify an issue that came up in the comments, by Gauss's lemma a monic polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ iff it's irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, and by reduction $\bmod p$, if a polynomial is irreducible $\bmod p$ for any particular prime $p$, then it's irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. So once you know that the polynomial is irreducible $\bmod q$ for any prime $q$ which is a primitive root $\bmod p$, it suffices to exhibit one such prime.

Unfortunately, as far as I know this is no easier than Dirichlet's theorem. Among other things, it's a straightforward exercise to show that Dirichlet's theorem is equivalent to the assertion that for any $a, n, n \ge 2$ such that $\gcd(a, n) = 1$ there is at least one prime (rather than infinitely many primes) congruent to $a \bmod n$.

Regarding your last comment, Eisenstein's criterion is still much, much, much easier to prove than Dirichlet's theorem, even with all of the details filled in.